# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable from unittest for api

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, flask-restful

This is the logs I received from my unittest for my APIs flask application which is using flask-restful, it showed that I have an int object not iterable error.

Really appreciate if anyone tell me what is actually wrong in my unittest codes :(

```
.
======================================================================
ERROR: test_brand_create (test.brand.BrandTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/david/ITP-Team3/test/brand.py", line 37, in test_brand_create
    response = tester.post('/api/brand/', data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
  File "/Users/david/.local/share/virtualenvs/ITP-Team3-bpvJtb_C/lib/python3.10/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 1140, in post
    return self.open(*args, **kw)
  File "/Users/david/.local/share/virtualenvs/ITP-Team3-bpvJtb_C/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/testing.py", line 217, in open
    return super().open(
  File "/Users/david/.local/share/virtualenvs/ITP-Team3-bpvJtb_C/lib/python3.10/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 1089, in open
    response = self.run_wsgi_app(request.environ, buffered=buffered)
  File "/Users/david/.local/share/virtualenvs/ITP-Team3-bpvJtb_C/lib/python3.10/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 956, in run_wsgi_app
    rv = run_wsgi_app(self.application, environ, buffered=buffered)
  File "/Users/david/.local/share/virtualenvs/ITP-Team3-bpvJtb_C/lib/python3.10/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 1255, in run_wsgi_app
    for item in app_iter:
  File "/Users/david/.local/share/virtualenvs/ITP-Team3-bpvJtb_C/lib/python3.10/site-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 462, in __next__
    return self._next()
  File "/Users/david/.local/share/virtualenvs/ITP-Team3-bpvJtb_C/lib/python3.10/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers/response.py", line 50, in _iter_encoded
    for item in iterable:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

======================================================================
ERROR: test_brand_put (test.brand.BrandTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/david/ITP-Team3/test/brand.py", line 49, in test_brand_put
    response = tester.put('/api/brand/'+id, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
  File "/Users/david/.local/share/virtualenvs/ITP-Team3-bpvJtb_C/lib/python3.10/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 1145, in put
    return self.open(*args, **kw)
  File "/Users/david/.local/share/virtualenvs/ITP-Team3-bpvJtb_C/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/testing.py", line 217, in open
    return super().open(
  File "/Users/david/.local/share/virtualenvs/ITP-Team3-bpvJtb_C/lib/python3.10/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 1089, in open
    response = self.run_wsgi_app(request.environ, buffered=buffered)
  File "/Users/david/.local/share/virtualenvs/ITP-Team3-bpvJtb_C/lib/python3.10/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 956, in run_wsgi_app
    rv = run_wsgi_app(self.application, environ, buffered=buffered)
  File "/Users/david/.local/share/virtualenvs/ITP-Team3-bpvJtb_C/lib/python3.10/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 1255, in run_wsgi_app
    for item in app_iter:
  File "/Users/david/.local/share/virtualenvs/ITP-Team3-bpvJtb_C/lib/python3.10/site-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 462, in __next__
    return self._next()
  File "/Users/david/.local/share/virtualenvs/ITP-Team3-bpvJtb_C/lib/python3.10/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers/response.py", line 50, in _iter_encoded
    for item in iterable:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 11 tests in 2.370s

FAILED (errors=2)
```

Here's my test code that I had the error on:

```
# brand.py
    def test_brand_create(self):
        tester = app.test_client(self)
        headers = login(tester)
        payload = {'brandName': 'test1'}
        response = tester.post('/api/brand/', data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertEqual(response.content_type, 'application/json')
        

    def test_brand_put(self):
        tester = app.test_client(self)
        headers = login(tester)
        payload = {'brandName': 'test'}
        print("TYPE", type(get_id(app, Brand, 'test1')))
        print("VALUE", get_id(app, Brand, 'test1'))
        id = get_id(app, Brand, 'test1')
        response = tester.put('/api/brand/'+id, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertEqual(response.content_type, 'application/json')
```

and the utils code as well

```
# utils.py
def login(tester):
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    # put user and password in .env file
    payload = {'username': os.getenv("user"), 'password_hash': os.getenv("password")}
    response = tester.post('/api/user/login/', data= json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
    jwt_str = response.data.decode('utf-8')
    header_jwt= ast.literal_eval(jwt_str)
    return {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + header_jwt['jwt_token']}

def get_id(app, model, brandName) -> None:
    with app.app_context():
        test_query = model.query.filter_by(brandName=brandName).first()
        id_lookup = model.query.get(test_query.id)
        return str(id_lookup.id)
```

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in your question. Also, read [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: For those two test function, what it `self`?  Is that actually your Flask application?  `app.test_client` expects to be passed a Flask application, because that's where it is sending the requests.